# Provide url and store image from the url in a file in file system in groovy

Tags: image, url, grails, groovy, download

I am doing a project in grails using groovy to upload an image. I have been able to fetch a file from my-computer and store it in a location and display it from there. I wish to accept a url from the user during run time and store the image in the locaion and display from there. Help please

Comment: Are you saying that you want to download the file from the given URL and store that file locally then serve it?  Why can't you just serve the image directly from the URL?  What purpose is there to download and store it on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider Gregg's comment, but if you stay with your idea, this is the way I would do it:

```
new File("path/to/local/image.jpg").bytes = new java.net.Url("http://url.from.user/image.jpg").bytes
```